# No module named scipy.misc at tensorflow environment

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, virtualenv, anaconda

My tensorflow is installed by anaconda2-4.2 and my
OS is ubuntu 16.04LTS

When I activated tensorflow's virtualenv and ran this code:

```
from scipy.misc import imread
```

I got error message

```
No module named scipy.misc
```

After deactivated tensorflow and execute the same code, there's no error. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I need to ran this code in tensorflow environment.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "activated tensorflow"?

Comment: mean typing command "source activate tensorflow" at terminal.

Comment: Can you try: `source active tensorflow`
`conda install scipy`?

Comment: Thanks, it works!!